# get data from PHP to jQuery for Hovercard - JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

ok so i am trying to use HoverCard on my website for the users that are registered on my site. how to i manage to get the data off the database using PHP and sending it to my jQuery script?

i know how to get data from PHP using jQuery but for some reason it is not working. Here is my code:

jQuery code:

```
var user = null;
$.post('userjson.php',{},
    function(output) {
        user = output;
    });

$('#loggedUser').hovercard({
    showCustomCard: true, 
    customCardJSON: user
});
```

PHP code:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];

$user_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'",$con);
$user_array = mysql_fetch_array($user_select);

$user = array(
    'name' => $user_array['username'],
    'bio' => $user_array['bio'],
    'image' => $user_array['propic']
);

echo json_encode($user);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `POST` is asynchronous so you must create the hover card in the callback

```
var user = null;
$.post('userjson.php',{}, function(output) {
    user = output;
    $('#loggedUser').hovercard({
        showCustomCard: true, 
        customCardJSON: JSON.parse(user)
    });
});
```

In your code the user variable was not set when you tried to create the hover card.

Comment: it helped! however this is the result that i get (link to picture - I'm new so i can't upload a picture yet...):

http://i.stack.imgur.com/DYeRM.png

Comment: that's odd, are you using the exact code you posted initially with my changes?

Comment: considering `link` shouldn't even exist as a function, you might want to post a jsfiddle or similar

Comment: sorry, if you could just post all of your code, including library includes so I can test it for myself.

Comment: i don't feel comfortable giving out access to my database, but if you have access to your own you can make it according to the code i gave you. the only other thing that you need to test it is the hover card script: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/jquery.hovercard.min.js"></script>

Comment: honestly, this doesn't make any sense to me, I recommend you try giving the hover card sample JSON, and then if it still fails you can verify that the issue is not in code provided here.

Comment: have you logged the incoming JSON to see its value?

Comment: perhaps you should look into the PHP response lacking a bio and an image

Comment: even if i take out the bio and image and just echo out the name, it still gives that "function link(){[native code]}"

Comment: so basically it prints it out correctly but it doesn't work when i put it in for the hovercard

Comment: I'm certain there is another issue. I suggest you review your code and post another question if necessary. The problem with the `POST` request was resolved.

Comment: OMG I GOT IT! ok so my problem was that i was using the POST function... i completely forgot about the $.getJSON() method and it works perfectly! Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: OK, I'm sorry. I should have realized your response was never parsed. `JSON.parse(user)` would work in the original code, as well.

Comment: no its all good. i probably could have worded the question better.

Comment: I meant to ask, would you please mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: the big check mark next to the answer? lol sorry this is my first posted question..

Comment: ok so new problem to solve with the hover card. i posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167076/hovercard-not-working-correctly-with-the-hover-function-any-ideas if you don't mind taking a look